# Update AngularJS current route failed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, symfony

I work on an editor which use AngularJS for client side and symfony 2 for server side (I think using symfony is trivial for my problem).

So my url have two parts : 
- symfony part to access to the editor
- angular part to navigate into editor

When user save his changes (via AJAX), I want to update symfony part to add generated id. So I manually build the new route with this js code snippet :

```
var newRoute = $location.protocol() + '://' + $location.host();

// Get symfony route (using FOSJSRouting)
newRoute += Routing.generate('innova_path_editor', {workspaceId: EditorApp.workspaceId, pathId: EditorApp.pathId});

// Add angular part
newRoute += '#' + $location.path();

$location.url($location.hash(newRoute));
```

When I print generated route in console, it's correct and when I copy/paste it in my browser, the page is correctly loaded.

But if I set url with `$location.url($location.hash(newRoute));`, Angular try to redirect me to my 404 route.

Thanks for help.

**EDIT**

Generated route is :

```
http://localhost/Claroline/web/app_dev.php/innova_path/workspace/2/path/editor/37#/global
```

**EDIT 2**

If it's possible, I'd rather not reload the page.

Comment: I think you're going to have to provide a more concrete example.  Can you tell me what your `newRoute` variable prints out when you do a console.log on it?  I suspect you're making this much harder than it needs to be and that you're really just looking to use `$location.path()` but I can't say that for sure without more information.

Comment: I have edited my post to add generated route. If I use `$location.path()`, I only have access to angular part (`/global`). But I have to update first url part (before `#`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to navigate to a different page or do full page reload, `$location` won't do what you want, you need to fall back to the `window.location`.

Change

```
$location.url($location.hash(newRoute));
```

to

```
location = newRoute;
```

#### Update:

If you're targeting modern browsers, you can use `pushState()` from html5 history api to avoid page reload.

Change

```
$location.url($location.hash(newRoute));
```

to

```
$timeout(function() {
    history.pushState(null, null, newRoute);
}, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for help. But if I can, I'd rather not reload the page. I forgot to put it in my question.

Comment: I have to add compatibility with older browsers so `pushState()` is not an option for me. I will reload my page until I find a better way to resolve my problem.